# Documentation form XML feed to update SharePoint

Tags: file-upload

I was interested in trying to update SharePoint by an `xml` feed. Is this possible and does anyone know any documentation I can read on to achieve this goal?

Comment: what you want to update in SharePoint by xml

Comment: the custom data list.  I want to be able that each main tag would indicate a row and each tag would represent a column.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own web service to receive the XML, and then use the object model to update the list you're trying to update. SharePoint supports custom ASMX web services installed to the _vti_bin directory. There are a lot more manual steps involved to deploy to SharePoint as compared to deploying an ASMX service to a standard ASP.NET application, but once it's set up, the service is good to go.

There's a "Hello World" tutorial here: [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx)

That should get you started.

## Note:

There is also support for WCF services in SharePoint, but they can not be hosted directly by SharePoint. If you can achieve your goal with ASMX, that is the recommended approach. WCF services are the appropriate choice if you need to use a different transport mechanism than HTTP.

See [Exposing WCF Services from SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650183.aspx)